# Sketching the graph of $2\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{4} )$

Tags: trigonometry

Sketching the graph of $2\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{4} ) $ for 1 cycle

Amplitude =$ 2 $

Period = $2 \pi $

Per quadrant = $2\pi /4 = \pi/2 $

Phase shift = $ -\pi / 4$

This is my sketch of the graph

[image]

My graph looks awfully weird , especially from $\frac {-\pi}{4} to \frac{3 \pi}{4} $ it is so Wide as compared to $\frac {3\pi}{4} to \frac{5\pi}{4} $

Every quadrant is about 1cm .

Is my scale wrong ? Or is this graph meant to be like that ?

Comment: Your scale is wrong. The spacing between $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$ should be equal to that between $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

On the positive sides, note that

$\frac{3\pi}4 - \frac{\pi}4 = \frac{2\pi}4$ but it seems to have the same length from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}4$

The scaling before and after $\frac{\pi}4$ seems different.